# C++: Mutable that creates huge internal change

Tags: c++, constants, mutable, const-correctness

Here's the thing:
I have a class that can store some data in two ways, this is, in two objects that represent the same data, small_type and big_type.
small_type is memory-efficient but has a bad access time, big_type is the opposite. big_type is only created on demand, from small_type.
The method to create big_type takes a long time, therefore we want to store big_type in the class, assuming that all methods guarantee consistency of the two variables.
As far as I understand const correctness, the class would look like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:

    (some constructors et cetera)

    SmallType get_small_type() const{
        return small_type;
    }

    BigType get_big_type() const{
        if(!big_type_created){
            create_big_type(); //will set big_type_created to true
        }
        return big_type;
    }

private:
    SmallType small_type;
    mutable BigType big_type;
    mutable bool big_type_created; //default false
    void create_big_type() const;
}
```

First of all, since I am a beginner, does this fulfill const correctness?
Here's my problem with this code: create_big_type() takes time, a lot of time (can take several minutes). This time is clearly visible from outside. So, while the logical state is not changed, it is clearly observable from the outside that something happens. Still correct?

Another question, is it acceptable style if there are setters that change small_type and set some boolean big_type_dirty true which would cause big_type to be created anew if demanded again?

Comment: I would reply ok on all your questions. The fact that BigType computation is visible from outside is something that may need further work (e.g. move this to a separate thread, but depends a lot on your application and other contextual infos not present here).

Comment: To me, the characteristics of `get_big_type` look a bit like `std::shared_future::get`: If someone has already computed the result, I can get it immediately, otherwise I have to compute it myself (e.g. `async` with default flags). `shared_future::get` is `const`, despite having to potentially modify the shared state. Note that `shared_future` also can tell whether or not additional work is required via `wait_for(0ms)`

Comment: As of C++11, many people expect `const` member functions to be thread-safe, by the way. So consider protecting concurrent access to `big_type` (e.g. when someone uses `get_big_type` and concurrently, the copy ctor of `MyClass`) or maybe even using a `shared_future<big_type>` instead of `big_type` as a data member.

Comment: big_type_created also has to be mutable. Doesn't your compiler tell you?

Comment: @n.m. Edited that. Of course it does, I didn't actually compile my reduced example and therefore didn't noticed my mistake.